# Automatically generating a prefixed hostname during Sysprep

Tags: windows, disk-image, sysprep

What I'm trying to do is set Sysprep to automatically rename the computer prior to joining the domain. If I put * in the answer file it generates a random name, but I would like to be able to apply a prefix to the name so that we can identify different generations of system images.

eg 2011JUNE-1AS6SDA76 is using the image from June 2011.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by agkeyser here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/604695dd-3ecb-4b8a-9735-21b557084013

If you set the RegisteredOwner & RegisteredOrganization in the "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" section under oobeSystem, then the auto generated name will be prefixed by the owner then the organisation.